# how to split a js object into an array of key-value pairs?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say I have an object like this:

```
var myObject = {
   X:1,
   Y:2,
   Z:3
}
```

Let's say I want to create a for loop to process each property on the object. The code below is just intended to be some pseudocode to communicate what I'm looking to do:

```
var properties = myObject.split();
for(var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++)
{
   var x = properties[i][key];
   var y = properties[i][value]
}
```

Can you recommend some code I can use to accomplish this in Javascript/TypeScript?

Comment: `Object.keys(myObject).forEach(key => { console.log(key, myObject[key]) })`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) function to get all the key and value pairs as an array of arrays:

```
Object.entries(myObject);
```

Which would return:

```
[['X', 1], ['Y', 2], ['Z' 3]]
```

And you could iterate through them:

```
for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(myObject)) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

Which would log out:

```
X 1
Y 2
Z 3
```

Do note that this is a relatively new feature with no support on IE nor Opera. You can use the polyfill from MDN or use any of the other methods (`for…in` with `hasOwnProperty`, `Object.keys`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = {
        X:1,
        Y:2,
        Z:3
    };


Object.keys(arr).map(key => { console.log(key, arr[key]) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```js
var arr = {
    X:1,
    Y:2,
    Z:3
};

for (var key in arr) {
    if (arr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + arr[key]);
    }
}
```

Another way you can do is

```js
var arr = {
        X:1,
        Y:2,
        Z:3
    };


Object.keys(arr).forEach(key => { console.log(key, arr[key]) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is typically using `Object.keys()`.

```
var keys = Object.keys(myObject);
for(var i = 0; i < keys; i++) {
  var key, value;
  key = Object.keys[i];
  value = myObject[key];

  // .. do something else ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this Object keys method. Create a custom function and add it to the prototype of the `Object` like,

```js
var myObject = {
  X: 1,
  Y: 2,
  Z: 3
}

Object.prototype.mySplit = function() {
  return Object.keys(this).map((key) => {
    return {
      key: key,
      value: this[key]
    };
  });
}

var properties = myObject.mySplit();
for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
  console.log(properties[i]['key'], properties[i]['value']);
}
```